# How can I keep gas execution cost as close to gas limit as possible?

Tags: gas, gas-limit, optimization

I notice that the percentage of total consumption varies across different functions on the blockchain.
For example: [this one](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x08ad33845f99b2c7773c675996a13ebb2d58baaba4693edea2866df7df681b94) uses 94%, while [this one](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5eb1ab18ae9e7ab6cd4191f50ef3727d11b1565790f8c49f6cbbfe6a9f291443) only uses 51%.

From a developer perspective, how can one optimize this to leave as little gas on the table as possible?

Comment: are you asking for gas optimization tricks

Answer (score 0):

1. Carefully select the appropriate data structure for the specific task. This includes choosing an efficient data structure like a linked list over an array when applicable.
2. Optimize the code for gas efficiency by using low-cost operations and avoiding expensive calls or loops.
3. Consider using cheaper alternatives like the Solidity assembly language for certain functions.
4. Carefully design the smart contract architecture to minimize the number of transactions and state changes.
5. Use the latest version of Solidity, which offers more efficient gas costs.
6. Utilize caching and other storage optimization techniques to minimize the amount of data that needs to be written to the blockchain.
7. Leverage off-chain computation to reduce the need for on-chain operations.
8. Use debugging tools to identify gas-inefficient functions and optimize them accordingly.
9. Monitor the performance of your contracts to ensure optimal gas usage.